# Can I select a row with a condition where the previous and next row have a condition?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am using MYSQL and am looking for a way to only select a row where it's previous and next row have a field called fav_num with a value of '3'

For example I have 6 rows and two fields. The fields are ID and fav_number.

```
 ID| fav_num
 1 | 3
 2 | 2
 3 | 3
 4 | 7
 5 | 2
 6 | 9
```

I'd like to find a way to return the ID from the table where the previous and next row have a fav_num of 3.
This query would then return ID 2.

I apologize if my question sounds confusing.

Comment: are you specifically looking to return just the data for ID =2, or is this a general rule to get all entries in the DB with a fav_num = 2?

Comment: is ID always contiguous (no gaps)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work..

```
SELECT id
  FROM tab t
 WHERE t.id BETWEEN
       (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tab tp WHERE tp.id < t.id AND tp.fav_num = 3)
   AND (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tab tn WHERE tn.id > t.id AND tn.fav_num = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT a.id FROM test1 a WHERE 
3=(SELECT fav_num FROM test1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM test1 WHERE id <a.id)) AND 
3=(SELECT fav_num FROM test1 WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test1 WHERE id >a.id)) ;


SELECT a.id FROM test1 a WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM test1 WHERE     id <a.id) AND fav_num=3) AND 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test1 WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test1 WHERE  id >a.id)  AND fav_num=3) ;
```

I am not sure about the perfornance.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ID FROM tbl WHERE fav_num BETWEEN '1' AND '3';
```

Answer (score -1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6fb0/12

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    @d1:=0+@d2 d1,
    @d2:=0+@d3 d2,
    @d3:=fav_num d3,
    @previd:=@id prevID,
    @id:=id 
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM t1 
  ORDER BY id) t
) filter
ON filter.d1 = 3
   AND filter.d3 = 3
   AND t1.id = filter.prevID
;
```